# Interaction.Behaviors, EventTriggerBehavior command is not invoked

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp

Below is onload event trigger from my XAML   view.

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior.Actions>
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}" />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior.Actions>
    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Appointments}" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:Appointment">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <StackPanel Margin="20,20,0,0">
                        <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{x:Bind Name}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{x:Bind Category }" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Name="ResultTextBlock" FontSize="24" Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold" />
</Grid>
```

Command implementation here.

```
 public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
               : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute,
               Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }


    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
        {
            CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecute == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

}
```

Command is not getting executed. Thanks for the help in advance.

i tried the viewmodel like this.View model has the Onload Command which calls the asychronous method ExecuteLoadedCommandAsync to give the result

```
 public class AppointmentViewModel : ViewModelbase
{       
    public List<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

    public DelegateCommand LoadedCommand { get; }

    public AppointmentViewModel()
    {
        LoadedCommand = new DelegateCommand(async (param) => await ExecuteLoadedCommandAsync());
    }

    public async Task ExecuteLoadedCommandAsync()
    {
        Appointments = await AppointmentService.GetAppointments();
    }      
}
```

Still it did not work.

Comment: You are holding the ViewModel inside the Command? not the Command inside the ViewModel?

Comment: i am new to UWP/WPF . Could you please correct this? I tried this     public DelegateCommand LoadedCommand { get; }

        public AppointmentViewModel()
        {
            LoadedCommand = new DelegateCommand(async (param) => await ExecuteLoadedCommandAsync());
        }
      
        public async Task ExecuteLoadedCommandAsync()
        {
            var response = await AppointmentService.GetAppointments();       
        
            AppointmentRetrivalTime = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppointmentCollection>(response).retrievalTime;
        }

Comment: You can edit your question and enter this code as a new part there. its unreadable this way...

Comment: i made the changes to the question

Comment: I think i get it now...? the Command doesn't need to know of the ViewModel. What you did in the VM is fine, but the Command doesn't need to have any connection to the VM. You did fine there also by providing a property to hold the Action. So the other question is whether your VM is actually loaded and stands as the DataContext of that view?

Comment: Try adding a "Private Set" to the "public DelegateCommand LoadedCommand { get; }"

Comment: tried this     DataContext = new AppointmentViewModel(); in my codebehind constructor

Comment: "codebehind constructor" of the View? that also fine.

Comment: Nope. private set could not help.

Comment: Maybe when the LoadedCommand is created the binding was already resolved. Try adding a setter to LoadedCommand property and put there a NotifyPropertyChanged call. Of course add a private ICommand backer property to help you with that.

Comment: Does the constructor of the `AppointmentViewModel ` get called at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the above code snippet. Actually the `ExecuteLoadedCommandAsync()` do executed. There is nothing wrong with the command of `InvokeCommandAction`. Adding a break point at `ExecuteLoadedCommandAsync()` method to test about this.

But the `Appointments` records cannot be loaded to the view. This is because when the view model new instantiate , the value of `Appointments` is null, and the value is set after `loaded` event executed. So for dynamic changed property you need to implement [`I​Notify​Property​Changed`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged) for `Appointments` property as follows:

```
public class AppointmentViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   //public List<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
   private List<Appointment> appointments;
   public List<Appointment> Appointments
   {
       get
       {
           return appointments;
       }
       set
       {
           if (appointments != value)
           {
               appointments = value;
               OnPropertyChanged("Appointments");
           }
       }
   }

   public DelegateCommand LoadedCommand { get; }

   public AppointmentViewModel()
   {        
       LoadedCommand = new DelegateCommand((param) => ExecuteLoadedCommand());
   }

   public void ExecuteLoadedCommand()
   {
       Appointments = GetAppointments();
   }

   public List<Appointment> GetAppointments()
   {
       List<Appointment> allappointments = new List<Appointment>();
       allappointments.Add(new Appointment() { Name = "name1", Category = "category1" });
       allappointments.Add(new Appointment() { Name = "name2", Category = "category4" });
       allappointments.Add(new Appointment() { Name = "name3", Category = "category3" });
       return allappointments;
   }
   #region INotifyPropertyChanged
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   {
       if (PropertyChanged != null)
       {
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }
   }
   #endregion  
}
```

Code behind for the XAML View:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    AppointmentViewModel vm = new AppointmentViewModel();
    this.DataContext = vm;
}
```

More details please reference [Data binding in depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth).